# Linux init script what does 0<&- &> achieve

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

I looking into writing my own `init.d` scripts to control several services running on my `Linux` server. I came across an example online which contained:

```
nohup $EXEC_SCRIPT 0<&- &> $LOG_FILE & echo $! > $PID_FILE
```

From what I understand:

- `nohup` Catches the `hangup` signal
- `$EXEC_SCRIPT` is a variable containing the command to be run
- `0<&- &>` Not come across this before
- `$LOG_FILE` similar to `$EXEC_SCRIPT` but contains the log file path
- `&` starts logging to `$LOG_FILE` in the background?
- `$!` is the PID of the most last background command
- `>` writes the result of `$!` to the `$PID_FILE`

I can work through it with this knowledge but the `0<&- &>` is completely throwing me off. I don't like to include things that I don't at least partially understand first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are redirections.

- `0<&-` closes the file descriptor 0 (standard input).
- `&>` redirects both stdout and stderr (in this case to the logfile)

Are you sure there was no `echo` before `$!`? `$!` would be interpreted as a command and most probably result in a

```
-bash: 18552: command not found
```

Comment: You are correct, there was an `echo` before `$!` thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

&<- closes the file descriptor.  But more fundamentally, searching for those little "&" atoms on Google can be painful!  See [this site](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial) on bash redirection for background info.